# How to show a default value in chart Android?

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I am developing chart for my Android app using achartEngine. i want to get the chart as below. 
The series 2 is the default value I should show. How can I do that? I'm totally new to android. 
[image: like this]

Comment: `the default value I should show`. Do you mean yow want to show a **reference line**?

Comment: @DerGolem yea... Series 2 line

Comment: So, simply add a new series with a fixed value in its array. Easy.

Comment: @DerGolem gerring **dataset and renderer should be not null and should have the same number of serie** this error

Comment: Sure. The arrays must be the same length. Say the real data contains 12 values. The reference line array also must contain 12 times the same value repeated (so to plot a 12 point straight line).

Comment: @DerGolem oke let me try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66252/discussion-between-android-lover-and-der-golem).